# Using a querystring to highlight a menu item

Tags: php, query-string, highlight

So I'm trying to use a query string to highlight a 'current' menu item.

Say the url is www.....something.php?tag=Music

And I'm looping through this code to check the $tag against a record in the database:

```
<li class="<?php if(isset($_GET['tag']) && $_GET['tag'] == $record->name); 
{ echo 'current'; }?>">
<a href="?tag=<?php echo $record->name; ?>">
<?php echo $record->name; ?></a></li>
```

Why doe's it always come out 'true' and echo 'current'.

The html it outputs is this:

```
<li class="current">
<a href="?tag=Music">Music</a>
</li>

<li class="current">
<a href="?tag=Film">Film</a>
</li>

<li class="current">
<a href="?tag=biscuits">biscuits</a>
</li>
```

Surely it should only be 'true' for 'Music'?

Comment: please also paste your loop code

Comment: show the entire loop please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semi-colon after your `if` statement.  Remove that and it should work:

```
<li class="<?php if(isset($_GET['tag']) && $_GET['tag'] == $record->name)
```

For shorter code, and if you have short tags enabled, try:

```
<li class="<?=isset($_GET['tag'])&&$_GET['tag']==$record->name?'current':''?>">
```

Comment: Tim Withers you're a genius - I was looking at that for hours! Thank you, thank you, thank you.